# Print Phd thesis in A4 or A5?

Tags: phd, thesis, formatting

I would like to ask those in Academia who supervise PhD students and get to read their Phd theses. When checking on previous theses submitted to the library, I found some printed not in the more common A4, but A5 format, half the size of A4.

I was wondering whether is is more comfortable for supervisors to read a thesis of roughly 200 pages (just counting the main matter) in A4 or A5 format? My thesis would contain some "normal-sized" tables and figures.

Comment: The inclusion of the image seems unnecessary and makes the question much harder to read than necessary. If one is not familiar with standard A4 paper, then seeing the numbers will probably not matter, and it is simple enough to describe A5 as half an A4 page.

Comment: Thank you Tobias, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It might depend on the university, but as far as I know, normally you submit one version to your phd committee and only then after they are done with you, you have to submit a truly final version to the library (which most likely no one will ever read, so small print in A5 might just be a cost saving measure).

Comment: In the Netherlands, the most common size for a PhD thesis is close to B5: 170x240 mm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, just checking the library is not enough — there might be restrictions on the format and only the relevant office can tell you what those restrictions are (if any).

Secondly, if you find out that you do have a choice (between A4 and A5 paper, for example), the natural thing to do would be to ask would be your supervisor in what format they would like to read your thesis.

(After submitting several printed copies of the thesis for review, you may get some of them back after your thesis defence, which you can submit to the library.)

Answer (score 1):

> is it [easier] to read a thesis of roughly 200 pages...in A4 or A5 format?

A4 seems advantageous to A5 if the font size is the same, because more fits on the page.

A4 remains advantageous to A5 with a smaller font size to fit the same information on a single page, if the reader finds smaller fonts harder to read.

A5 is advantageous to A4 if reading on-the-move, because A5 is more compact (and might even fit in the reader's pocket).

Ultimately, more information about the reader needed to definitively answer your question. If you're interested in your examiners' preferences, then you could ask them (just make sure they each have an identical copy!).

Comment: I assume that if two versions are available, they would need the same pagination, meaning that the font sizes wouldn't be the same.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I agree that different font sizes are likely, but that information isn't provided

Comment: True enough. And given that advisors may be the proverbial aged-aged-man (i.e. me), reducing font size is problematic.

Comment: Again, I agree (_smaller fonts harder to read_ ~ _reducing font size is problematic_ for _the proverbial aged-aged-man_)